# Comparing non null-terminated char arrays

Tags: c, arrays, compression, unsigned-char

I have a compressed `unsigned char` array of a known size. Due to compression considiration I don't store the null-terminator at the end. I want to compare it to another array of the same format.  What
would be the best way to do so?

I thought duplicating the comparessed arrays to a new array, add the null-terminator, and then compare them using `strcmp()`.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: Or you can simply loop over the arrays and compare their elements.

Comment: The standard memory compare function is called [memcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `strncmp()` function from `string.h`

```
strncmp(str1, str2, size_of_your_string);
```

Here you can manually give the size of string(or the number of characters that you want to compare). `strlen()` may not work to get the length of your string because your strings are not terminated with the `NUL` character.

**UPDATE:**

see the code for comparison of unsigned char array

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main()
{

unsigned char str[]="gangadhar", str1[]="ganga";
if(!strncmp(str,str1,5))
printf("first five charcters of str and str1 are same\n");
else
printf("Not same\n");

}
```

Comment: Does strncmp work on unsigned char strings as well? @Gangadher

Comment: @DavidTzoor yes, it does.

Comment: @DavidTzoor yes, it works see the simple example added to the answer.

Comment: Actually, it will only work for your case -- *compressed* binary data -- because this typically will not contain zero bytes. Any zero byte will terminate the strncmp operation prematurely -- [strncmp definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/).

Comment: For c++, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strncmp) says: "The behavior [of strncmp(lhs, rhs, count)] is undefined if lhs or rhs are not pointers to null-terminated strings.", however, it looks like it's safe for C.

Answer (score 3):

two years later, but...

I believe ‘memcmp‘ is the function you want to use, since ‘strncmp‘ may stop if it found a zero byte inside the compression string.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the size of the array, you could use `strncmp()`:

```
int strncmp (char *string1, char *string2, int n)
```

with `n` being the number of characters to compare.

Deets: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_strncmp.htm